# Multiple security realms

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, jaas

I tried having multiple security realms in my application, but I get exception during deployment:

> Message: Multiple login-config elements detected

web.xml fragment:

```
....
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Admin Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin Pages</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>mb-domain</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
...
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Besides this being a violation of the spec, your use case is not clear. Why would you ever need multiple login-configs? How would the container know which login-config to use for the restricted URLs in the app?

Comment: @CoolBeans "Why would you ever need multiple login-configs?" - Many use cases -> Allow the user to chose how to login (just logout of this very website and look at the login options it presents you), or have different authentication mechanisms for different segments of the app. And there's even the use case of having an automatic fallback (try token first, if it fails fallback to username/password transparently)

Comment: @guest "I tried having multiple security realms" - What you've shown are *authentication mechanisms* not realms. Realm as term is kinda ill defined in Java EE, it can mean "identity store" as well.

Comment: @dextermeyers you can provide people multiple ways to authenticate, but the actual login-config is still has to be one. The other parts would have to be done programmatically via configuring additional JAAS Login modules which can be stacked if needed.

Comment: @CoolBeans I was speaking more in a theoretical, future aimed way. A future Java EE could have multiple "login-config" entries and a way to combine (stack) these.

Comment: @CoolBeans "via configuring additional JAAS Login modules" - What if the server is not using JAAS Login modules? The question mentioned JBoss and they re-use the JAAS LoginModule interface (but they do so many special things there you can't call it plain JAAS anymore), but other servers like Tomcat or Liberty don't use JAAS at all. What was the famous saying again? Jaas is not the universal standard that you may think it is.

Answer (score 5):

Only one `<login-config>` can be used per web module deployment descriptor.

According to §14.2 of the [Servlet Specification v. 3.1](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340):

> ## Rules for Processing the Deployment Descriptor
>
> [...]
>
> - The sub elements under `web-app` can be in an arbitrary order in this version of the specification. Because of the restriction of XML Schema, The multiplicity of the elements `distributable`, `session-config`, `welcome-file-list`, `jsp-config`, `login-config`, and `locale-encoding-mapping-list` was changed from “optional” to “0 or more”. The containers must inform the developer with a descriptive error message when the deployment descriptor contains more than one element of `session-config`, `jsp-config`, and `login-config`.

Alternatives:

- Use programmatic authentication (based on either JASPIC or whatever facilities your Java EE / Servlet implementation offers).
- Use EAR packaging (if a single authentication strategy per module is acceptable).
- Drop container-managed authentication.